# Rules for line continuation in bash code?

Tags: bash

Why can

```
for (( expr1 ; expr2 ; expr3 )) 
do commands 
done
```

be written as:

```
for (( expr1 ; expr2 ; expr3 )) 
do 
commands 
done
```

where `do commands` can be written in two lines without error, while

```
for (( expr1 ; 
expr2 ; expr3 )) ; ...
```

will be wrong?

What is the general rule about continuation into next line in bash?  Thanks.

Comment: I can't think of too many languages that would allow a carriage return in a `for` statement.

Comment: ...though a trailing backslash can always be used to allow a line continuation...

Comment: I was going to try to reference the section of the [shell grammar](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10) that talks about this but I can't actually find it. Is this for loop syntax a bash-ism? Anyway, the issue is that the internal `;` aren't statement separators there and are, instead, syntactical I think. So you can't swap a newline in for them the way you can with a semicolon in other places.

Comment: @EtanReisner - You're correct, `;` isn't a statement terminator (like C), it's a statement *delimiter*.

Comment: @Mr.Llama While correct about my misuse of term that doesn't actually impact the point of the statement or the relevance to the question.

Comment: @EtanReisner: I think the syntax was introduced in ksh93, but it's never been part of Posix. $((...)) and ((...)) were present in the original ksh, iirc, but only `$((...))` made it into Posix (although Posix recognizes that shells may implement `((...))`

Comment: ... http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges lists the feature as being implemented in 2.04-devel, with the note saying "ksh93". So I guess that's a confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way

```
for (( expr1 ; expr2 
; expr3 ))
```

Will not work as now it is two separate commands

```
for (( expr1 ; expr2
```

and

```
; expr3 ))
```

Both of which are not complete commands and so will cause an error.

Whereas

```
do 
commands 
done
```

evaluates to

```
do (nothing)
commands
done
```

which is the same as

```
do;commands
done
```

which is the same as

```
do;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;commands
done
```

As multiple commands can be put after do, then the first line is seen as an empty command.Just as you can leave lines between separate commands outside of the loop.

P.S i realise this answer is a bit bumbling so if anyone understands what i mean and whats to clean it up then feel free :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a "general rule" about the use of newlines in a shell. However, the [shell grammar](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10_02) (which is the basis for shells such as bash) explicitly marks locations where an explicit newline is part of a command. These include:

- Prior to or following a `compound_list`, which is why it is possible immediately after `(`, `{` (when used to start a compound command), `do`, `elif`, `else`, `for`, `if`, `then`, `until` and `while`, and immediately before `)` and `}` (when used to terminate a compound command).
- After `&&`, `||` or `|`
- Between statements in a list, or following the `;` or `&` which separates statements in a list.
- Before the `in` in a `for` or `case` statement
- In a clause of a `case` statement, after the pattern which starts the clause or the `;;` which terminates it.
- Maybe some other contexts which I missed :)

In addition, newlines are ordinary characters when quoted with backslash, double quote or single quote, and are removed from the input if preceded by a backslash outside of single-quoted strings.

The Posix grammar does not define the `for ((expr;expr;expr))` syntax, which comes from `ksh93` and was incorporated into `bash` in v2.04. However, in that construct, the semicolons are part of the syntax, and are used to separate arithmetic expressions, not statements. Since these semicolons are not statement separators, they cannot be replaced with newlines. However, `bash` does allow them to be *followed* by newlines.